# How to recover data from SharePoint hosted app if it accidently uninstalls

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am currently building SharePoint hosted app using custom lists on the appweb . If someone accidentally uninstalls the app, all the data is lost when the app cleans up after itself.Is there any way to recover all data in appweb lists?

Comment: No, you can not recover that data from SharePoint lists from appweb.

Comment: @Dikesh Gandhi: Why don't you post your reply as answer instead of comment?

Comment: @pholpar:Because I thought it's not a proper answer or proper question.

Comment: One way to restore it is content db backup.